# null in annotation RestController with method Post

Tags: java, spring, http-post, tomcat7, spring-restcontroller

I ran a Spring project with Apache tomcat7 in Windows Server(It worked Normally), recently change the OS to CentOS7(for resource issue). 
Have 1 Big Problem with Conversion to Linux.
It install CentOS7 and setting same configuration(tomcat7, jdk 1.7).
Maven Build in Win10, Eclipse Luna -> Deploy Root.war in CentOS, tomcat7 Webapp.
And i send Request, it always null(request.getParameter("id"))

i use ajax(method:post) in client and use @RestController at Contoller.
When i change method to 'get' it worked.
I am so confused in this case(it worked perfectly previously in Windows OS).

attached code :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/loginCheck",
        data: {'uid':uid, 'passwd':passwd},//$("#frm").serialize(),
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

---

```
    @RestController
    public class SysController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, String> loginProc(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
    String passwd = request.getParameter("passwd");
    System.out.println("uid=" + uid);
    System.out.println("passwd=" + passwd);
    Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
    while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
        String paramName = (String) params.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Parameter Name - " + paramName + ", Value - " + request.getParameter(paramName));
    }
    return map;
}
```

---

```
    <properties>
     <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
     <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
     <mybatis.version>3.2.8</mybatis.version>
     <mybatis-spring.version>1.2.2</mybatis-spring.version>
     <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
     <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
     <jackson.version>2.5.2</jackson.version>
     <poi.version>3.11</poi.version>
     <maven.tomcat.url>http://mold.ubidom.com/manager/text</maven.tomcat.url>
    <maven.tomcat.path>/</maven.tomcat.path>
    <tomcat.username>pcw</tomcat.username>
    <tomcat.password>pcw1234</tomcat.password>
    </properties>
```

---

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```